# Coded UI test failing with Chrome driver

Tags: selenium, coded-ui-tests

Result Message:

Test method CodedUITestProject13.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw an exception:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'OpenQA.Selenium.IllegalLocatorException' from assembly 'WebDriver,
>   Version=2.53.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1c2bd1631853048f'.

It launches Chrome browser and loads the website, executes the login step and then fails with the above exception.

I am fairly new in using Coded UI and any help will be great.

Comment: By selector I do not understand what you mean?

Comment: Can you please add the code that is throwing this error

Comment: Looks like a missing reference to me along with some invalid selector that is trying to throw this exception.  Can you verify that you have included references properly?  Can you include the rest of the code?

Comment: Need to share your code as well..

Comment: By Code do you all mean the Coded UI test method?

Comment: also, this test method works fine with IE.

Comment: can you put here the piece of code where your test fails?